# Binomial probability, rolling dice

Tags: probability

A die is rolled 30 times , what is the probability that 6 turns up exactly 5 times?

(30 choose 5)* 1/6ˆ5 * 5/6ˆ25 ?

What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely, parenthesis around 5/6 are missing. Otherwise, nicer math formatting would make it better readable, but doesn't make it wrong.

Comment: i.e. ${30 \choose 5} \left( \frac{1}{6} \right)^5 \left( \frac{5}{6} \right)^{25}$